# Summing numbers of a txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need a function which opens up a txt file and adding all the numbers within it.

I have tried a few different functions after researching online but none has so far worked.

```
def sum_this(txt):
    """
    >>> sum_digits("numbers.txt")
    1000
    """
    fileop = open(txt)
    red = fileop.read()
    nums = red.split()
    sums = int(nums)
    total = sum(sums)
    return total
```

The "numbers.txt" contains:

```
500
200
150
150
```

Numbers have no dots they are in different lines

Need this to work with python-2.7

What needs to be changed with the above code to work?

Comment: Interpret with `python-2.7` interpreter. :)

Comment: Could you give us an example of such a text file? Is it separated by dots, slashes etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Compact (and safe - you are not closing your file) way:

```
def sum_this(txt):
    with open(txt, "rb") as f:
        return sum(int(num) for num in f.read().split())
```

Answer (score 1):

`nums` is a list, so you need call `int` on each of its elements, as:

```
sums = map(int, nums)
```

Comment: Could you also include `open(txt, 'r')`?

Comment: `'r'` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 sum = 0;
 fileop = open(txt, 'r');
 A = readlines(fileop);
 for i in range(0, len(A)):
     sum = sum + A[i]
 return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice one liner :

```
def sum_this(text_file):
    return sum(map(int, (open(text_file,'r').read().split('\n')))
end
```

You basically read it in the `open` part, then `read()` it into a string and split it based on the `nextLine` attribute. I have python-2.7 and it works for me.